# Vue warn: Unknown custom element: <myCompont> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a freshman, when i use use custom components, it gives me this error:

> Vue warn: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?

The `ModalBase` compontent used in the components `NoticeModal.vue` and  `NoticeModal` compontent used in the `productInfo.vue`.

I'm  sure I had correctly import `NoticeModal` in `productInfo.vue` and also import `ModalBase.vue` in `NoticeModal.vue`, and all registerd.

But I get the only warn: `Unknown custom element: <modal-base>`

Here is `ModalBase.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <slot name="header">
        <p class="title">This is base</p>
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "ModalBase",
  data() {
    return {show: ''}
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is `NoticeModal.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="noticeModal">
    <modal-base>
      <div slot="header">hello</div>
    </modal-base>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import {ModalBase} from '@/components/index';
    
export default {
  name: "NoticeModal",
  props: ['modalOptions'],
  components: {
    ModalBase
  },
  data() {
    return {show: ''}
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is `productInfo.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <notice-modal></notice-modal>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import {NoticeModal} from '@/components/index';
    
export default {
  name: "productInfo",
  components: {
    'NoticeModal': NoticeModal
  },
  data() { }
}
</script>
```

By the way this path `'@/components/index'` is right,  both `NoticeModal`and `ModalBase` had imported and registered and exported correctly in this file.

And in `@/components/index`:

```
import NoticeModal from '@/components/componentsFile/NoticeModal.vue'
import ModalBase from '@/components/componentsFile/ModalBase.vue'
    
export {
  NoticeModal,
  ModalBase
}
```

Comment: Why components/index? This can be the fail, try with a relative path, ends like /components/ModalBase and after write your feedback

Comment: components/index this file is used for export all my components...

Comment: Can you show how you export data in components/index?

Comment: <pre>
import NoticeModal from '@/components/componentsFile/NoticeModal.vue'
import ModalBase from '@/components/componentsFile/ModalBase.vue'

export {
    NoticeModal,
    ModalBase
}
    </pre>

Comment: why didnt you import NoticeModal from NoticeModal.vue file than import from component/index?

NoticeModal.vue
import {ModalBase} from '@/components/ModalBase';

Comment: Just now, I did it as you told.it  works. the modalBase compontents path i import in the noticeModal.vue should write  as  ' @/components/componentsFile/ModalBase.vue'.  thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
components: {
        'NoticeModal': NoticeModal
},
```

These lines means you've registered a component named 'NoticeModel'. So in your template code, you should use this component with "NoticeModel" as html tag.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <NoticeModel></NoticeModel>
    </div>
</template>
```

Also you could use following code to register a HTML style tag and use it with **notice-modal**

```
components: {
    'notice-modal': NoticeModal
}
```

Comment: or if you only writes NoticeModal, you can use camel or kebab case.

Comment: So, you should either register your component as `components: {
            'modal-base': ModalBase
        }` or use `<ModalBase></ModalBase>` in your file.

Comment: Thanks I got a new point。 I did it as you suggested，it still gives the warn。The problem  ：‘NoticeModal’ component  in productInfo works，The ‘NoticeBase’ component in  NoticeModal.vue dosen't work.

Comment: Have you did the same change to *NoticeBase** as **NoticeModal**? I mean use `components:{'modal-base':NoticeBase}`.

Comment: I'd hope you can post your modified code or just push your code to github or a *CodePen** project, I was wondering if there was any other point went wrong and I didn't notice.

Comment: Hi, the problem is  soluted , 
 in NoticeModal.vue, when i 
 import ModalBase, write the path  as ‘@/components/componentsFile/ModalBase.vue’. this is just ok。 Not as ‘@/components/index’。 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you can get this error.
You have two files with same name and different extensions

**like**: MyComponent.vue and MyComponent.js in same folder.

In my MyComponent.js I added a name to solve this error.

`export const componentWorker = {
    hello: (p1) => {console.log('hello from (JS) ' , p1)},
    name: "JSCompWorker"
}`

This don't always happen - I have other samename.vue and samename.js in
one folder, and no problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should import your component directly. for example:

instead of

```
import {ModalBase} from '@/components/index';
```

put

```
import ModalBase from '@/components/ModalBase.vue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom elements can be defined outside of Vue, when an external script is loaded for ex.

With **Vue2** you can explicit in the config the elements to ignore with `ignoredElements`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements

I don't know how to this with Vue3...

PS: If you have to interact with such kind of custom element in Vue, you may want to wait for the Vue component to be [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and use [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to be ensure the composant is ready to use.