# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <app> - did you register the component correctly? (found in <Root>)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to setup Vue in Laravel 6.

I've ran:

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue

npm install && npm run dev

Then inside of welcome.blade.php, i've deleted the body of the welcome page and added a div with the id of root.

I can get the example component to show in the browser but I can't create any new components and get them to show without getting the error. I've even tried just renaming the example-component and even that won't work. I renamed the file to App.vue, and then renamed everthing else - see below:

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('app', require('./components/App.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Journey To Dev</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <app></app>
    </div>

  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

The App.vue is unchanged from ExampleComponent.vue, i just renamed the file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try running `npm run dev` again and hard refresh the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue warn: Unknown custom element: <myCompont> - did you register the component correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408041/vue-warn-unknown-custom-element-mycompont-did-you-register-the-component-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run

```
npm run dev
```

Again everytime you change Javascript assets or Vue components so that Webpack recompile them to `public/js/app.js`

Or even better, boot up a watcher and let it recompile when you change code

```
npm run watch
```

And make sure to hard refresh or leave the devtools console open so cache would be disabled

You can also automatically register components like so

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
```

instead of

```
Vue.component('app', require('./components/App.vue').default);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i've ran npm run dev several times, and run npm run watch

Comment: If you run it **after** changing the files and test on a private window in your browser, it should work... I just copied your code in the question and it does work

Comment: Hard refresh just worked though!! Even though i've done hard refresh about 10 times already! Thanks very much

Comment: I did it after, its the hard refresh that was needed - not sure why it didnt work the previous times? oh well

Comment: Glad it worked, consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: the hard refresh was the answer in the end, could you add that to the answer. May help others in the future

Comment: Leaving the devtools open is also better, you can just refresh because cache would be disabled

Comment: Hmm i did have the devtools open as i was constantly running npm run dev, hard refreshing and checking the console - but it didnt work. Until you said it, I tried it again and it did! Who knows what was going on!

Comment: Who knows ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks again Saly!